# How to include a configuration-dependent project output in WiX 3.6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.6

I'm wondering, how to include a configuration-dependent project output in WiX Setup Project?
For example, let's look at Visual Studio solution with one .NET application and one Wix Setup Project.

I've added a reference to .NET app in Setup project and created component in setup source:

```
  <Component Guid="EB0CBC32-5AE5-41B3-A343-FEBE044AC30A">
    <File Source="$(var.MyApp.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

So, I expect, that WiX will include a **release** version of MyApp in its **release** setup msi, and debug version in debug msi respectively. Otherwise, reference to the project output makes no sense for me.

But there's always debug version.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE.**

Here's candle's command prompt from VS output window:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: **MySetup, Configuration: Release x86** ------
>           C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.6\bin\candle.exe -d"DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\" -dSolutionDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=Wix_ProjectOutput.sln -dSolutionName=Wix_ProjectOutput -dSolutionPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Wix_ProjectOutput.sln -dConfiguration=Release -dOutDir=..\Release\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MySetup\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=MySetup.wixproj -dProjectName=MySetup -dProjectPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MySetup\MySetup.wixproj -dTargetDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=MySetup.msi -dTargetName=MySetup -dTargetPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\MySetup.msi
>   **-dMyApplication.Configuration=Debug** -d"MyApplication.FullConfiguration=Debug|x86" -dMyApplication.Platform=x86 -dMyApplication.ProjectDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MyApplication\ -dMyApplication.ProjectExt=.csproj -dMyApplication.ProjectFileName=MyApplication.csproj -dMyApplication.ProjectName=MyApplication -dMyApplication.ProjectPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MyApplication\MyApplication.csproj -dMyApplication.TargetDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Debug\ -dMyApplication.TargetExt=.exe -dMyApplication.TargetFileName=MyApplication.exe -dMyApplication.TargetName=MyApplication -dMyApplication.TargetPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Debug\MyApplication.exe -out obj\Release\ -arch x86 Product.wxs

Why for the **release** build of MySetup was used **debug** configuration of MyApplication??

**UPDATE 2**.

And here's candle's command prompt, when using msbuild from command line:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe /verbosity:d /t:rebuild /fileLogger /p:Configuration=Release  Wix_ProjectOutput.sln
```

In `msbuild.log`:

> C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.6\bin\candle.exe -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*" -dSolutionDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=Wix_ProjectOutput.sln -dSolutionName=Wix_ProjectOutput -dSolutionPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Wix_ProjectOutput.sln -dConfiguration=Release -dOutDir=..\Release\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MySetup\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=MySetup.wixproj -dProjectName=MySetup -dProjectPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MySetup\MySetup.wixproj -dTargetDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=MySetup.msi -dTargetName=MySetup -dTargetPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\MySetup.msi **-dMyApplication.Configuration=Release** -d"MyApplication.FullConfiguration=Release|x86" -dMyApplication.Platform=x86 -dMyApplication.ProjectDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MyApplication\ -dMyApplication.ProjectExt=.csproj -dMyApplication.ProjectFileName=MyApplication.csproj -dMyApplication.ProjectName=MyApplication -dMyApplication.ProjectPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\MyApplication\MyApplication.csproj -dMyApplication.TargetDir=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\ -dMyApplication.TargetExt=.exe -dMyApplication.TargetFileName=MyApplication.exe -dMyApplication.TargetName=MyApplication -dMyApplication.TargetPath=D:\Projects\Research\Wix_ProjectOutput\Release\MyApplication.exe -out obj\Release\ -arch x86 Product.wxs

So, under msbuild all is OK.

**UPDATE 3**.

Looks like WiX uses **active** build configuration (see combobox at VS toolbar).
I mean, if `Debug` is selected there, WiX projects will include debug output of referenced projects. If `Release` is selected, WiX projects will include release output.

This behavior isn't correct from my point of view. `Debug` installer must include **debug** output of referenced projects. `Release` installer - **release** output.

Posted bug [here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3558938&group_id=105970&atid=642714), but now it is closed without any explanation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You may use $(var.Configuration), which is set to solution configuration (Debug, Release, etc...):

```
<File Id="MyApp.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\MyApp\$(var.Configuration)\MyApp.exe" />
```

Comment: The method might be right, but the details seem wrong:
1.) Built binaries are placed in (projectdir)\bin\(configuration). The above example missed the bin directory.
2.) By default, only Debug and Release builds are built under bin, others are built under bin\x86\(configuration). The example can't cater for this possible difference in directory depth.
I'm using $(var.(projectname).TargetDir)

Comment: You are probably right about the project path, and after closer inspection I can tell my answer was wrong anyway, or at most could only be used as a temporary workaround. Looks like TC problem was indeed a lack of knowledge about Configuration Manager, like mheyman noted below.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a variable of `MyApplication.Configuration` and set it to `Release` by following steps:

1. Right-click on the References node of the project in the Solution Explorer and choose Add Reference...
2. In the Add WiX Library Reference dialog, click on the Projects tab.
3. Select the desired project(s) and click the Add button, then click OK to dismiss the dialog.

Details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx).

Comment: This variable is already defined, and its value is `Debug`.  
I've posted a bug at WiX tracker, but now it is closed without any explanation. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do exactly what you are attempting regularly with success, I suspect you are confusing the solution configuration with the project configuration. A solution configuration of **foo** can use a project configuration of **bar** - they are just names and they do not have to match. Check the configuration manager (***BUILD → Configuration Manager...*** in VS2012) and verify that when your solution configuration is "Release" that your project configuration is also "Release".